# uploading image in django

Tags: python, django, error-handling, image-uploading

I'm writing a simple file uploader for a website. The user sees a form:

```
<form action="/user_profileform/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uform" id="userform">{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="usubmit">
</form>
```

and upon submit, I redirect to this function:

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    print "arun";
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_profileform/')
    else:
    print "ranjeet"
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('user_profile.html', {'form': form })

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks(): 
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

When I try this functionality out, I'll always get an exception:

IOError at /user_profileform/

[Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/ghrix/ghrixbidding/media/images/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to open `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` which is directory.

Comment: when i try this destination = open('/home/ghrix/ghrixbidding/static/media', 'wb+') than it will display :- IOError at /user_profileform/ [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/ghrix/ghrixbidding/static/media' – user2644708

Answer (score 1):

Because settings.MEDIA_ROOT is directory. You need to provide filename for handle.
Is better to use Model with FileField, because it generates unique file name in media automatically. It is described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: media root is defined in settings.py

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/ghrix/ghrixbidding/media/images/'

Comment: when i try this 

destination = open('/home/ghrix/ghrixbidding/static/media', 'wb+')

than it will display :-

IOError at /user_profileform/

[Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/ghrix/ghrixbidding/static/media'